# PHPMailer : replace the default messageID

Tags: php, html, nginx, smtp, phpmailer

I send emails using PHPMailer, evthg works well but I would to set a uniq MessageID for each email.

PHPMailer version : "v5.2.16"

(loaded with Composer from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.git)

I found the documentation here :
http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_MessageID

so here is what I tried :

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 ...
 $mail->MessageID = md5('HELLO'.(idate("U")-1000000000).uniqid()).'-'.$type.'-'.$id.'@domain.com';
```

**Result :** This is always the default MessageID generated by PHPMailer :

[image]

and not mine... :(

Then I tried sthg more simple :

```
 $mail->MessageID = "blablag@domain.com";
```

**Result** : KO (the same)

The documentation indicates that we can set a MessageID, and it should be a string, I don't understand at all why it doesn't work...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The structure of `MessageID` should be:

```
<sometext@sometext>
```

If your `MessageID` doesn't have this exact structure - PHPMailer will ignore your `MessageId` and generate it's own MessageId.

You can change your code to:

```
$mail->MessageID = "<" . md5('HELLO'.(idate("U")-1000000000).uniqid()).'-'.$type.'-'.$id.'@domain.com>';
```

And it should work.

Comment: yes I looked the preg_match rule in the phpMailer class and it was that, I forgot to close my question, stupid mistake.. but thank you!