# retrieve $MessageID from phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have just set up phpmailer, and i want to store messages in a log table on send.

phpmailer creates a messageid automatically, how can i retrieve $MessageID it so i can store it in my table ?

i don't need to set it, but i tried this...

```
$MID = time() .'-' . md5('xxx@gmail.com' . 'yyy@gmail.com') . '@domain.com';
$mail->MessageID = $MID;
```

and the header on the sent email is different

would be happy just to retrieve the default one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method [getLastMessageID](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_getLastMessageID) that you can use.

How about [setting your own value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39857135/3866610)? You must remember, that

> the structure of MessageID should be:
>
> `<sometext@sometext>`
>
> If your MessageID doesn't have this exact structure - PHPMailer will
>   ignore your MessageId and generate it's own MessageId.

Comment: perfect, getLastMessageID worked great for me  - thanks

Comment: `$mail->getLastMessageID` not working in me though...